# Multi-level menus: show submenu, hide it's parent with jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu

I got a css menu that I would like to apply some jquery in order to expand it's functionality. In particular, when viewed by mobile devices, I would like it's parent menus to be replaced by the sub-menus (meaning to completely hide the parent ones) and that to work for all deeper levels (as if entering directories on an ftp client and you don't see the tree). But I am facing a problem right from the beginning. I got this code so far that hides the first parent but does not show the sub-menu. I would like to understand why (what I do wrong there), I would also like to see an example of how this could work if you are so kind.

```
var submenu = $('#menus li ul li');
submenu.hide();

$('#menus li:has(ul)').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menus li').hide(function()
    {
        submenu.show();
    });
});
```

I found all other cases on google except this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `submenu` is descendant of the menu and you hide menu, how can it be shown???

Comment: I got no way to do this with css, but not with jquery either ? thanks for your answer.

Comment: You'd have better to provide a jsFiddle to let people see what you are expecting here

Comment: something like this: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

Comment: But in your link, menu is not hidden. BTW, why don't you use it then if it is what you are looking for?

Comment: All top level gets hidden when clicking on one item, check it. I don't use it cause I want to write my own for many reasons, one is learning how to do it.

Comment: Menu is not hidden, only clicked anchor tag is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples you shared, they are hiding the anchor tag as pointed out by A. Wolff

[Here's a quick and dirty example where you would nest `<ul>` inside of `<li>` and toggle display: none; and display: block;](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/F5kg7/7/)

In this example you hide all the  and show the  which is it's sibling, which would ultimately hide the first level of the li and show the second.
HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="forward">first</a>
        <ul class="second-layer">
            <a class="back">back</a>
            <li>Second layer Menu 1</li>
            <li>Second layer Menu 1</li>
            <li>Second layer Menu 1</li>
            <li>Second layer Menu 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.second-layer{
    display: none;
}

.hide a{
    display: none;
}

.show a{
    display: none;
}

.show a.back{
    display:block;
}

.show .second-layer{
    display: block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.forward').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('show');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hide');
});

$('.back').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('show');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: thanks MathiasaurusRex, in the example you show I still get all the parent menus showing after clicking on one of them though.. (well except the one I clicked, but I want to hdie all of them)

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/F5kg7/7/ also updating my answer a bit.

Comment: yeah this works. I was messing with `visibility:hidden` with some success, but this one looks like a better solution. thanks man.

Comment: Quick note, traversing up the dom  aka using .parent(), isn't the absolute best solution. But it does help clearly explain and show how things are shown / hidden.

Comment: Do you have a better solution in mind at all with such a thing ? I wish I could do it with pure css. And that is what I was trying the last minutes by using jquery `addClass`. It felt a little unstable though.

Comment: JQuery addClass is an appropriate solution here, because you want to keep your Javascript (functionality) and CSS (Styling) seperated. On clicking the anchor tag (functionality / javascript) you're calling a new menu style (styling / css)
What I was referring to was writing a more elegant javascript solution, in which I'm not quite confident in my own skills to elaborate to you for fear of leading you down the wrong path. =)

Comment: After all, your input opened my eyes on the issue, I will try to get it done with as much css as possible after your last comments. Again thanks, there are some very nice people on this site.